# Lift Record does not validate list elements when calling `validate` - bug or feature?

Tags: scala, lift-record

When `validate` is called on a `Record` it recursively calls `validate` on each field. However, if a field is a list like `BsonRecordListField` then it does not have any `validations` registered by default which leads to elements of a list not being validated when `validate` is called from parent scope.

It's not difficult to override `validations` on a list field to map over all elements to get truly complete validation. I wonder though if that behaviour is by design or is it a bug? To me it seems more natural to validate all fields and their elements (list elems in this case).

Override could look like this for example:

```
object listOfThings extends BsonRecordListField(this, SomeBsonMetaRecord) {
  override def validations = ((elems: ValueType) => elems.map(_.validate).flatten) :: super.validations
}
```

The problem is that you have to remember to do it for all list based fields.

I'm just guessing that implementation is left to the user because of the `flatten` there, i.e. there could be multiple errors from multiple elements but with the same `FieldIdentifier` - not clear which element in the list caused an error - need to come up with a custom way to differentiate errors by element position or otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got reply from Tim Nelson who created a ticket to address this: https://github.com/lift/framework/issues/1587, milestone 3.0-M2. This might still be discussed but looks like it will probably get fixed.

Discussion on lift google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/liftweb/gh2syNeGWyw/OC3y2TLWfAkJ.